# Closure of Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, hilbert-spaces

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and $\Delta$ the (positive) Laplace-Beltrami operator. Now, consider this operator as an operator

$$\Delta:\mathcal{D}(\Delta)\to L^{2}(M)$$

There are two natural domains one might consider:

$$\mathcal{D}_{1}:=C_{c}^{\infty}(M)$$
$$\mathcal{D}_{2}:=\{f\in L^{2}(M)\cap C^{\infty}(M)\mid \Delta f\in L^{2}(M)\}$$

> To the closures $\overline{\Delta:\mathcal{D}_{1}\to L^{2}}$ and $\overline{\Delta:\mathcal{D}_{2}\to L^{2}}$ agree?

Of course, is is clear that $\overline{\Delta:\mathcal{D}_{1}\to L^{2}}\subset\overline{\Delta:\mathcal{D}_{2}\to L^{2}}$, but the other direction is not so clear to me.

EDIT: I know that the answer to this should be positive, since in the ltierature, one can find proofs that $\Delta$ both defined on $\mathcal{D}_{1,2}$ is essentially self-adjoint and hence they have a unique self-adjoint extension. But I was looking for a more direct argument, without relying on the non-trivial fact of essentially self-adjointness.

Comment: This (essential self-adjointness) is really the crucial fact and the natural argument here. For example, if you ask the analogous question for $-d^2/dx^2$ on $L^2(0,1)$, the operators do not agree because this time $-d^2/dx^2$ on $C_0^{\infty}(0,1)$ is not essentially self-adjoint.